# Auto resize table to fit screen

Tags: excel, excel-2010, vba

I have an excel table that queries a DB - the amount of rows it returns fluctuates.

Does anyone know how to auto resize the table when the amount of rows change so that the entire table always fits in the screen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds as though you're referring to the zoom. All credits to [Chip Pearson](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/zoom.htm) for this handy sub.

Example usage: `call ZoomToRange(activesheet.cells(1,1).currentregion, true)`

```
Sub ZoomToRange(ByVal ZoomThisRange As Range, _
    ByVal PreserveRows As Boolean)
'http://www.cpearson.com/excel/zoom.htm
Dim Wind As Window

Set Wind = ActiveWindow
'
' Put the upper left cell of the range in the top-left of the screen.
'
Application.Goto ZoomThisRange(1, 1), True

With ZoomThisRange
    If PreserveRows = True Then
        .Resize(.Rows.Count, 1).Select
    Else
        .Resize(1, .Columns.Count).Select
    End If
End With

With Wind
    .Zoom = True
    .VisibleRange(1, 1).Select
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: WOW.  Thanks for sharing this.